# Angularjs change $get source on click

Tags: ajax, json, angularjs

I have a web page that uses

```
app.controller('listCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://data.com/?region=north").success(function (data) {
        $scope.properties = data;
    });
});
```

On the click of a button, I'd like to reload the source from a different URL

```
$http.get("http://data.com/?region=south").success(function (data) {
    $scope.properties = data;
});
```

Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encapsulate the getting of the resource in a function that is parameterized, so you can call it once when the controller is initializing, and any time they click the button after that.

```
app.controller('listCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

    function getResource(region) {
       $http.get("http://data.com/?region=" + region).success(function (data) {
          $scope.properties = data;
       });
    }

    $scope.changeRegion = getResource; // provide function for button click

    getResource('north'); // initialize default
});
```

View:

```
<button type="button" ng-click="changeRegion('south')">Change Region</button>
```